# the application not responding dialog (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7 32 bit on dell vostro 3500

specifications are:
intel core i3, 2GB RAM, 320 GB hard disk, no graphics card

The problem is:
Randomly the OS shows this dialog and all applications stop responding.

```
Microsoft Windows     
The application is not responding. The program may respond again if you wait.      
Options: END PROCESS or CANCEL
```

when I click on End process, everything except wallpaper disappears and force shut down is only option.

I've tried:
CCleaner, disk de fragment, scanned with ESET

Answer (score 1):

Did u check the event viewer ?
If u didn't get the problem try starting the system in normal.
To Start the system in normal mode "type msconfig in run and choose the normal startup"
If it didnt solve, try to boot in safe mode
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode